# Wordpress deploy results with a 304 error and redirecting to :8888

Tags: apache-2.2, deployment, wordpress

I have wordpress blog, which works perfectly on localhost. In the letter from my hosting there was line

> Please place all of your Internet files in the /public_html directory.

So, i've uploaded all the files there, then exported mysql db through phpmyadmin and checked for all the paths in the code to be absolute. However, when I'm trying to reach my domain, it results me with

> 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE):

and changing the url from

> mydomain.com

to

> mydomain.com:8888

What could be the problem, in which way should I look? Hosting is running under the Cpanel and uses apache.

Comment: Ok, i've found the solution [here](http://mswebnetwork.net/helpdesk/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=160). Please answer the question, so I would be able to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found all the [solutions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) to resolve problem as this on wordpress official website.

Answer (score 3):

1. Login to your hosting account control panel (cPanel)
2. Go to your PhpMyadmin Page
3. Choose the database of your wordpress which has experience this issue
4. Click the wp_options and search the siteurl and home
5. Edit the option_value (http://localhost:8888) to your new URL (example: http://wordpresspage.com)